# SQL update query according to row sequence number

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table and I want to update this table using SQL query statement.
How can i write a statement to update the 3rd row for example?
What I mean is that I want to make update to a certain row according to its appearance sequence in the table.

Comment: show what you have tried... and post some codes and your tables structure....

Comment: Add sample table data, before and after the update.

Comment: Rows has no any sequence in the Sql table. Sql DBMS is free to return rows at any order if no ORDER BY clause is specified.

Comment: let's say that my table is like this:
name   age   level
nour      12      4
mike       13     5
rik          14      1

and i want to update the third row, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

> 3rd row

When ordered by what?  SQL databases make no guarantee to the order of records in any given query unless explicitly given an `ORDER BY` clause.

Identify the row you want to update using a `WHERE` clause.  For example:

```
UPDATE SomeTable SET SomeColumn = 'Some Value' WHERE AnotherColumn = 'Another Value'
```

You can chain together lots of boolean logic into that `WHERE` clause to create more complex ways of identifying the record(s) you want to update.  But the point is that you have to identify the record.  "The 3rd row" doesn't mean anything to SQL.

---

Once you *do* have that `ORDER BY` clause, you can perhaps do something a little more complex.  For example, sort the records in a sub-query and use an identifier from that query.  So you might get "the 3rd row" like this:

```
SELECT ID FROM SomeTable ORDER BY ID OFFSET 2 LIMIT 1
```

Then use that in the `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE SomeTable SET SomeColumn = 'Some Value'
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM SomeTable ORDER BY ID OFFSET 2 LIMIT 1)
```

(assuming MySQL, since you didn't specify, but other RDBMS engines have similar capabilities)

Comment: hello, thanks for your fast reply. what i want is to edit the third row of the table without any order, only according to its appearance order in the table. and i don't want to use other columns cause i'm generating a dynamic code and in my code the user is able to edit all the columns of the table so i don't know on which column i should depend to put it in the where condition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which DBMS you're using. If you're using Oracle DB there are pseudocolumns ROWID and ROWNUM you could use for this purpose.